# Is encryption required to store non-PAN data under PCI DSS?

Tags: pci-dss

We do not store PAN card data, but we do store other non-PAN data such as expiration date, billing zip, and cardholder name.  We store this info for use with card-on-file tokens provided by our payment processor.  Do we need to encrypt this non-PAN data in our database without the PAN?

We expect to qualify for PCI-SAQ D under PCI DSS 3.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we need to encrypt this non-PAN data in our database without the
>   PAN?

No.  To quote the DSS, "*If PAN is stored with other elements of cardholder data, only the PAN must be rendered unreadable according to [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2-1.pdf) Requirement 3.4.*"  We can assume that when stored with tokens or other non-PAN data, this non-requirement stands, because "*[PAN]  is the defining factor for cardholder data.*"

The first quote is from page 8, which also has a nifty table showing what must be rendered unreadable:

[image: Data Encryption Table from PCI DSS 3.2.1]